# No cyrillic symbols in a string in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

i've started developing in IntelliJ in Java, created a new gradle project, added a few libraries but encountered a problem that a string is not being filled with cyrillic symbols - instead i get incorrect symbols (screenshot attached). How can i fix it? It has something to do with encodings - I tried a lot of suggestions on the web but nothing helped. Cheers! [image: here is the image]

Comment: Is this only happening in debug mode? Or also when you print this to the output?

Comment: Only when debugging + when i try to use the string somewhere (send it through through some APIs). Console output is ok

Answer (score 1):

Just change all encodings into `UTF-8` (or other preferable encoding) and reload all java files into `UTF-8`.

You must know  how to do first part (if you don't: `File(top left corner of your window)>Settings>Editor>File Encodings`).

The second part is also easy: just click on encoding in bottom right corner of the window and choose `UTF-8` (or other preferable encoding).

Then you will have window like shown below. Choose "Reload" and enjoy. If you still have questions you are free to ask.

Here better description: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html

[image]